# Can't run SpecFlow tests from Visual Studio with MSTest

Tags: specflow

I had this working on a previous project and now on a new project I've setup SpecFlow, got it generating tests from my feature file but I can't run the tests from the feature file and instead have to go to the code behind to run the tests. I've also installed the VS extension "Spec Flow for Visual Studio". What can I try?

Comment: Check your app.config to make sure MSTest is the unit test provider because it defaults to NUnit.

Answer (score 3):

as Greg suggested the first thing to check is that your config is set up correctly for ms test. you basically need this:

```
<specflow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MSTest"/>
</specflow>
```

Also worth checking your generated feature.cs tests to see what unit test language they are in

Comment: I believe this is all setup correctly. I'm going to double check and update OP with details.