# SpecFlow MsTest: No tests to execute

Tags: mstest, specflow

I've created a SpecFlow project and I can run its tests from Test Explorer in Visual Studio.

I've [added this to App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28913208/492336):

```
<specflow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MSTest"/>
</specflow>
```

But when I try to run them from the command line using `mstest`, it can't find any tests to execute:

```
c:\Workspace\Test>mstest /testcontainer:SpecFlow.Tests\bin\Debug\SpecFlow.Tests.dll
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26208.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading SpecFlow.Tests\bin\Debug\SpecFlow.Tests.dll...
Starting execution...
No tests to execute.
```

Any idea what's wrong with my command line?

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an absolute path to the `/testcontainer` parameter

```
c:\Workspace\Test>mstest /testcontainer:c:\Workspace\Test\SpecFlow.Tests\bin\Debug\SpecFlow.Tests.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

vstest.console.exe can run all types of tests even with console.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" %PROJECT_NAME%.Tests.dll'
```

was the solution for me